# How to automatically allow my service to interact with the desktop at installation time?

Tags: .net, windows-services, permissions, installutil

I have a Windows service built which is being installed by .NET 2.0's `installutil /i` command. It installs the service as with the following account, with a password:

```
NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
```

When I run my service with `net start <serviceName>`, I get

```
Error 5: Access Denied
```

To remove it I've had to open up `services.msc` and from the Properties give the service

```
Logon As -> Local System Account
         -> Allow Service to interact with desktop.
```

Can I put this whole “clicky” business into code which is either native .NET C# code or WMI or some other Batch script? I'll be using a batch script anyways so either is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Figured out an Answer, thanks very much to the following Webpage to which I give full credit.

[link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2007/05/08/setting-windows-service-account-c-and-wmi.aspx)

Here's the Solution I have, just change your service name as needed. Throw it in a C# Console App and run it :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string serviceName = "SERVICE_NAME_HERE"; 
    string objPath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName);
    using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objPath)))
    {
        object[] wmiParams = new object[11];
        wmiParams[6] = "LocalSystem";
        wmiParams[7] = "";
        service.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot the "Desktop interact" part. Just add wmiParams[5] = true;